# C++ const function with reference

Tags: c++

In this function :

(Counter is the class in which the function operator++ is declared)

```
const Counter& operator++ ();
```

What means the const for my function ? I don't really understand the const keyword in combination with pointers or references !

Comment: It returns a constant reference of the type `Counter`. The `const` applies to the function only if it appears at the end of the declaration.If it appears at the beginning of the declaration it applies to the type being returned.

Comment: but const makes something unchangeable, and what can't I change now?

Comment: [Const Correctness](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/const-correctness.html). This will help you understand :)

Comment: @HansPeter this depends of your implementation of class Counter. *You* define what a const Counter means. E.g. defining an object of a class as const, no member variable can be changed (this means they are all const also), also not from member functions. And you may only call const defined (at the end of function name) member functions of this object. But you could change this whole meaning, when working with pointers as member variables: you cannot change the adress the pointer is pointing on, but the content, even from a const defined object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that you may not use this reference to change the object it referes to. For example if you have two objects of type Counter

```
Counter obj1, obj2;
```

then you may not write

```
++obj1 = obj2;
```

because due to the qualifier const the object refered to by the reference returned by operator ++ is immutable.

If you would remove the const qualifier in the operator declaration then this statement

```
++obj1 = obj2;
```

would be valid.

In fact it is not a good idea to declare the preincrement operator returning const reference. Usually it declared  without the const qualifier

```
Counter& opperator++ ();
```

In this case it behaves the same way as the preincrement operator ++ for arithmetic tyoes. For example this code is valid

int x = 1;

++x = 2;

and the result is x = 2;

Answer (score 1):

This is an operator overload, but the declaration syntax is similar to a function. Your declaration can be split into 3 parts:

- the return type: `const Counter&`
- the function name: `operator++`
- and the parameters type: `()` (no parameters)

So `const Counter &` tells you that the function will return a constant reference to a `Counter` object. A constant reference makes so that the object can't be modified.

For example:

```
Counter c1;
++(++c1); // invalid
```

Here `(++c1)` returns a `const reference` to a `Counter` object. This reference is incremented, but is invalid, because this reference can't be modified (it's constant).

Comment: You confuse the preincrement operator with postincrement operator showing expression Counter c1;
(c1++)++; // invalid

Answer (score 0):

To illustrate my comment here an example:

```
class xy
{
private:
    int i; // const int i when object of xy is const
    int *ptr; // int *const ptr when object of xy is const

public:
    xy() : i(0), ptr(&i) { } // const i initialized to 0, only possible in constructor
                             // ptr pointing to i

    void set (int s) { i=s; } // changes i, not possible to define this member function
                              // as const like read()

    int read () const { return i; } // reads i

    void ptr_set (int s) const { *ptr = s; }
};

int main ()
{
    const xy obj;
    int read = obj.read(); // read() is allowed for const objects

    obj.set(10); // not allowed! you could not define set() as const (like read()):
                 // there would be a compiler error, because this member function
                 // would try to change const i

    obj.ptr_set(10); // allowed, would change i through pointer

    return 0;
}
```

Btw, can anyone explain why something like `obj.ptr_set(10)` is after all possible in sense of const correctness?